# Parsing specific JSON Object with regex

Tags: regex, json, parsing, jmeter, beanshell

i have a json string goes like

> {
>
> > ```
> > "someKey": [],
> > "aKey": {
> >     "someKey": "some value",
> >     "someOtherKey": "some other value",
> >    ...
> > },
> > "anotherKey": [],
> > "module": [{
> >     "someOtherKey": "some other value",
> >     "specificKey": "specific value",//here is the key and value couple i know
> >     "someOtherKey": "some other value"
> > }, {
> >     "someOtherKey": "some other value",
> >     "someOtherKey": "some other value",
> >     "someOtherKey": "some other value"
> > }],
> > "somekey": "someValue",
> > "someOtherkey": [] }
> > ```

i need a regular expressions which should return only objects like this:

> {
>           "someOtherKey": "some other value",
>           "specificKey": "specific value",
>           "someOtherKey": "some other value"
>       }

in addition in the module array there may be more than one object having that specific key-value couple..

normally i would parse and loop through the whole JSON string but i have to do it with regular expression.

I've tried this:

```
(\{.*,"specificKey":"specific value",.*\}*)
```

but it returned me thw whole JSON string.. Any help?
Thanks in advance!

**UPDATE**
if it's possible with beanshell i can use it too. I'm using JMeter and need to parse the response to create another response.

Comment: I am curious, why this have to be done with a regular expression?

Comment: Regex is not good for parsing JSON. Use right tool for the job - use JSON parser!

Comment: I'm using JMeter and couldn't solve the problem with beanshell.

Comment: You may have better luck making all operators non-greedy:

Comment: I think this might be what you are looking for http://theworkaholic.blogspot.ca/2012/05/json-in-jmeter.html

Comment: Thank you the link worked. I think i've missed it when i was searching for solution.

Answer (score 0):

Is there any specific reason for not to use [JSON Path Extractor](http://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/JSONPathExtractor/) JMeter plugin?

If you don't have limitations like "Vanilla JMeter without any plugins" you're welcome to download "Extras with Libs Set" from [JMeter Plugins download page](http://jmeter-plugins.org/downloads/all/).

For reference you can use [this guide](http://blazemeter.com/blog/using-xpath-extractor-jmeter-0) (scroll down to `Parsing JSON`)